# Generics name clash

Tags: java, generics, name-clash

Consider:

```
public interface Foo<T> {
    public static class X{}
    public void foobar(T t); 
}

public class Bar<X> {
    Foo<X> foo = new Foo<X>() {
        public void foobar(X t) {}
    };
}
```

I found no way to express that I mean the `X` from `Bar<X>` and not `Foo.X` in the `foobar(X t)` implementation. Is there no other way than renaming the generic parameter `X` in `Bar` or the static inner class?

Comment: That doesn't look right... can you nest a public class (even static) inside an interface?

Comment: Yes, if you rename either the static inner class or the generic parameter of Bar, it compiles.

Comment: @Daniel ... Yes you can. It looks funny, but its completely valid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to disambiguate to the type parameter, and I think that that was a reasonable design decision to make.

1. The conventions are clear that type parameters should be one character long if possible, and the flipside to this is that other classes shouldn't have one-character names.
2. If you had the ability to disambiguate, *then you would have the ability to rename the type parameter `X` in `Bar<X>`*.  In other words, if you had the ability to say `foobar(TypeParameter.X t)` you would have the ability to simply use something other than `X` for the type parameter on `Bar`.  Renaming `X` *is the way* you avoid name clashes.

Don't forget that type parameter names don't leak out to other classes in more than trivial ways.  You are never forced to use a *certain* type parameter name, ever.  So it makes sense that the language designers wouldn't have thought this is worth adding complexity to the language for.

Comment: I tend to agree with your second point, but not with the first one: Java's lack of syntax for pretty basic things like Closures or Tuples forces you to use wrappers, and if you work on code heavily relying on these wrappers, you quickly start to use names like `F` or `P` instead of `Function` or `Product` (see e.g. http://www.functionaljava.org ).

Answer (score 0):

the compiler wont even bother to determine if you meant Foo.X, it will consider the TypeParameter X, regardless, unless you typed something like:

```
public class Bar<X> {
    Foo<X> foo = new Foo<X>() {
        public void foobar(Foo.X t) {}
    };
}
```

Comment: No, that's not true. Inside the anonymous class we are in the scope of class `Foo`, so `Foo.X` shadows the type parameter `X` of the outer class.